# Running this code gives me a timeout exception error, why?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build a script to automate filling in a textbox with selenium, but I cant seem to get it to work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
import time

browser = 
webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/xiang/PycharmProjects/testo/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://zbib.org/')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
name = "form-control form-control form-control-lg id-input"

try:
    input = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
    name)))
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

I expected there to be no error and the browser/driver doesn't quit, but I get this error in the terminal and the browser/driver quits:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xiang/PycharmProjects/testo/bib.py", line 14, in 
<module>
    input = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
name)))
  File "C:\Users\xiang\PycharmProjects\testo\venv\lib\site- 
   packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Can you please try with `input = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='form-control form-control form-control-lg id-input')))` and let me know still if you see the same error.

Comment: Yeah gave me the same error.

Comment: And if that does not work, I am sensing there might be an iframe where you have the this input field in such case you have to switch to iframe first before waiting for the element.

Comment: Can you please share the html of the element and chrome devtools screenshot that shows the hierarchy of the element.

Comment: Ok thanks, ill try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can definitely throw an Exception.
`WebDriverWait` will throw a TimeoutException if it does not meet the request after the timeout set time.

You can ignore the exception by adding this:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
try:
    input = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
    name)))
except TimeoutException:
    pass
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

Since your className has spaces you should be using css selector. Your name variable would be:

```
name = ".form-control.form-control.form-control-lg.id-input"
```

Your code would then be:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
try:
    input = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    name)))
except TimeoutException:
    pass
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

To ensure your browser will be closed you can also use the context manager like this:

```
name = ".form-control.form-control.form-control-lg.id-input"
chromedriver = 'C:/Users/xiang/PycharmProjects/testo/chromedriver.exe'

with webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver) as browser:
    browser.get('https://zbib.org/')
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    try:
        input = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, name)))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```